# Capacitor v3 Some Errors

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

When ı update my capacitor to 3v ı get some warnings and error. How can i fix it ?

Warning 1 :

```
Using flatDirs should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
Currently detected usages:
- repository flatDir used in: project ':app', project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'
```

Warning 2 :

```
Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
Currently detected usages in: root project 'android', project ':app', project ':capacitor-android', ...
```

**Error :**

```
Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update android studio and it will work again !